# Private foursquare (or custom open-ended survey)

Tags: gratis, web-apps, collaboration

I'd like to collect lunching places with (1-2000) colleagues. I also would like my colleagues to rate and comment those places (and see all places and comments). Is there a free webapp suitable for that problem?

ps: It resembles for me a private version of foursqaure